# Product of stochastic matrix and (positive) diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, markov-process

Given a stochastic (all rows/columns, depending on convention, sum to 1; not generally symmetric) matrix $P$ and positive diagonal matrix $D$, is there a name for the matrices of the form $PD$? This matrix product is important in the use of Markov Additive Processes, where $D$ represents an exponential tilting factor, wrt dynamics $P$.

Of course, any non-negative matrix can be factorized this way. However, I am moreover interested in what happens if we change $D\to D'$ some other diagonal matrix. Some examples are if we perform a Hadamard/Schur/elementwise exponentiation $D \to D^{(\gamma)}$, if we swap rows and columns with a permutation matrix $S$: $D \to S^{-1} D S$.

The idea is that I'd like to use information about $PD$ to inform myself (in terms of approximations or inequalities) of the properties (especially Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue and eigenvectors) of $PD'$, where $D'$ is some transformed, positive diagonal matrix, with examples I've mentioned above. So: Are there names of these matrices and transformations? Are there results known or general literature I can read on?

Any thoughts or relevant literature for this area of research would be much appreciated.

Comment: By $E$, do you mean the identity matrix?

Comment: Not sure if there's a name for it. As you said, it's often done for non-negative matrices. I've seen it done in the context of "Diffusion Maps" where you factorize the weight/adjacency matrix of a graph using a diagonal matrix or certain powers of it. Depending on the power that you use, the asymptotics recover the diffusion of the Laplace-Beltrami operator or the Fokker-Planck equation.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oops, no I did not. I'll change the notation, should just be another arbitrary diagonal matrix.

Comment: Interesting, thank you @StefanLafon

Comment: Me and a colleague came across the same type of matrix in our research on reinforcement learning, we ended up not using it as much, but wrapped up our results in  https://arxiv.org/pdf/2304.11634.pdf.

Comment: @ifog That was my application as well! Check out the tilted (and driven) matrix in our (very) recent work here: https://journals.aps.org/prresearch/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.5.023085. I'll take a closer look at your work. Thanks for sharing

Comment: Thanks for the link, in our case we used it to define an extended softmax policy with lookahead for policy gradient (you can check out the citation in the pdf I listed if interested), I think the relation between the works comes from the equivalence between entropy regularization and its softmax solution. Very interesting, thanks!